# Función print imprime None

Tags: python

Todo funciona bien, sin  embargo, el `print` final me muestra `None` y no  sé a qué se debe. Pueden probar con la siguente cadena: `CCATT-AATGATCA-CAGTT`

```
def PorcentajeGC():
    cadenaADN= str(input("Ingrese la cadena de valores :"))
    cadenaADN= cadenaADN.replace("-","")
    cadenaADN= cadenaADN.upper()

    contA= 0
    contC= 0
    contG= 0
    contT= 0
    for s in cadenaADN:
        if s== "A":
            contA += 1
        if s== "C":
            contC += 1
        if s== "G":
            contG += 1
        if s== "T":
            contT += 1
    total= contA + contC + contG + contT
    porceC= 100*(contC/total)
    porceG= 100*(contG/total)
    final= print("El porcentaje de C es :",porceC,"%" "\n y el porcentaje de G es :", porceG,"%")
    return final
print(PorcentajeGC())
```

Comment: Estas haciendo un print de una función que ya tiene un print solo llama a la función y ya.

Comment: print() siempre retorna None porque es una función con retorno por defecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recuerda que print() devuelve el valor none en el código aunque muestre texto en consola.

Por lo que estas guardando `final= print("El porcentaje de C es :",porceC,"%" "\n y el porcentaje de G es :", porceG,"%")` corresponde a `final = none`. Por ello al final sale 'none' en la consola.

Una opción es que la función devuelva un `str` como salida y luego mostrarlo en consola con `print()`. De la siguiente forma:

```py
def PorcentajeGC():
    cadenaADN= str(input("Ingrese la cadena de valores :"))
    cadenaADN= cadenaADN.replace("-","")
    cadenaADN= cadenaADN.upper()

    contA= 0
    contC= 0
    contG= 0
    contT= 0
    for s in cadenaADN:
        if s== "A":
            contA += 1
        if s== "C":
            contC += 1
        if s== "G":
            contG += 1
        if s== "T":
            contT += 1
    total= contA + contC + contG + contT
    porceC= 100*(contC/total)
    porceG= 100*(contG/total)
    final= f"El porcentaje de C es : {porceC}% \n y el porcentaje de G es :{porceG}%"
    return final
print(PorcentajeGC())
```

Output:

```
El porcentaje de C es : 22.22222222222222% 
 y el porcentaje de G es :11.11111111111111%
```

Comment: Tiene un print de más... la funcion puede hacer el print por si sola. la variable final no es necesario si solo despliega el valor.

Answer (score 0):

otra forma es retornando el mensaje usando format

```
def PorcentajeGC():
    cadenaADN= str(input("Ingrese la cadena de valores :"))
    cadenaADN= cadenaADN.replace("-","")
    cadenaADN= cadenaADN.upper()
    contA= 0
    contC= 0
    contG= 0
    contT= 0
    for s in cadenaADN:
        if s== "A":
            contA += 1
        if s== "C":
            contC += 1
        if s== "G":
            contG += 1
        if s== "T":
            contT += 1
    total= contA + contC + contG + contT
    porceC= 100*(contC/total)
    porceG= 100*(contG/total)
    return ("El porcentaje de C es: {0} %\ny el porcentaje de G es: {1}%").format(porceC, porceG)
print(PorcentajeGC())
```