# Quitar el valor None al llamar al metodo de una clase

Tags: python, poo

Cuando hago el llamado al metodo, me imprime los pares clave:valor del diccionario pero al final me imprime un None. Si quito el print de la iteracion no me imprime todos los pares clave:valor (solo el primero).

Alguna solucion para que me deje de imprimir el None?

```
    def get_fiscal(self, name_sucursal):
        with open("data_fiscales.json", 'r', encoding=' utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            if name_sucursal == data['nombre sucursal']:
                for key in data:
                    print(f'{key}: {data[key]}')
                

maipu = Fiscales('Maipu')

print(maipu.get_fiscal('Maipu'))
```

Comment: Toda funcion devuelve None por default. Estas mandando a mostrar en pantalla el resultado de get_fiscal... Simplemente, quita el print que envuelve a get_fiscal

Comment: Gracias, no me habia fijado en ese pequeño detalle!!!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Función print imprime None](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466972/funci%c3%b3n-print-imprime-none)